# Angular routing fails when we type link directly into url

Tags: angularjs

I'm using angular routing with HTML5Mode turned on. Right now, when a user clicks on a hyperlink on my main page to /portal/books/xxx, he is shown a particular partial, but when he directly types it in the address bar, it won't work. Just wondering if there is a solution around that?

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/portal', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/books-index',
    controller: 'BooksIndexCtrl',
  })
  .when('/portal/books/:bookUrl', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/book',
    controller: 'BookCtrl'
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have your URL rewriting rules set correctly? Remember that in HTML5 mode, all requests should be directed to your index.html in order for this to work.

For Apache, add something like this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
```

For Nginx, in your virtual host config file, you can add something like this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
```